# Импорт персонажа с анимацией в Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d

Импортировал модельку с анимацией прыжка и бега с сайта Mixamo, там в готовой анимации не только анимация, но и изменение позиции, как это убрать, чтобы только анимация воспроизводилась, а то он выскакивает наружу парента.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам нужно посмотреть в сторону [RootMotion](https://docs.unity3d.com/ru/530/Manual/RootMotion.html). В этом мануале подробно описано, что есть 2 варианта событий в зависимости от настроек BakeIntoPose:

- либо движение запекается в "позу" персонажа - то есть вращение/движение происходит только с моделью, при этом сам GameObject не меняет вращение/положение
- либо анимация влияет на положение/вращение самого GameObject

Такая настройка может применяться к: вращению объекта, движению по оси Y и движению по оси XZ.

Данная настройка Roor Motion доступна только для моделей, которые импортированы как гуманоидные (humanoid) анимации. 
Для того, что установить такую настройку, выберите вашу модель в проекте, перейдите на вкладку Rig и установите значение параметра AnimationType на Humanoid. После этого на вкладке Animation у каждого анимационного клипа появятся поля семейства Root Transform.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: жаль, я что то не так делаю, у меня Bake Animations неактивен. С бегом данная проблема решил, когда поставил галочку на Loop Time и Loop Pose, а с прыжком только частично помогает: больше вперед не прыгает но по Y всё равно выпрыгивает с места. Где мне надо менять можете объяснить пожалуйста, в Префабе модельки есть вкладки  Model, Rig,Animation, Materials, тут менять или в Animatore выделив Jump?  Прошу Вас.

Comment: @PinPin добавил информацию в ответ

Comment: Спасибо огромнейшее человеческое